# Atom-editor, how to get rid of the "Authentication required" popup

Tags: atom-editor

How do I get rid of the "Authentication required" popup when I start Atom?
I am hardly using the atom-editor because the popup is getting really annoying.
I hope that someone can help to find the right setting for it. I suspect the automatic check for updates to be the culprit, but have no idea to turn that off either.

Comment: I used that editor for years and never remember an authentication prompt. Have you tried switching to Pulsar since it replaced Atom anyway?

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I had never heard of Pulsar. I knew that work was ongoing to create a community version of Atom but I missed the release. I hope that I can quickly set up Pulsar with all my personal Atom tweaks, without the authentication of course :-)